# RSYNC Does Not Delete Source Directories

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm using rsync to essential fetch files off a server, then delete the files from the server once I have them locally.  The full command I'm running is below.

This does successfully delete the **files** on the source server, however empty directories still remain.  I don't get any messages or errors.  All output is normal.  Perhaps this is the intended functionality.

How can I tell rsync to clean everything, including the directories?

`rsync --progress -vrzh --remove-source-files`

Version is 3.0.9 on both ends.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78375/move-files-and-delete-directories-with-rsync | https://serverfault.com/questions/384110/how-to-delete-empty-source-directories-when-moving-folders-with-rsync

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The behavior of `--remove-source-files` that you observe is exactly that specified by [`man rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> --remove-source-files
>
> ```
>    This tells rsync to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.
> ```

There is no specific command to remove the directories, as these two discussions in [StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78375/move-files-and-delete-directories-with-rsync) and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/384110/deleting-folders-with-rsync-move) clearly show. The solution suggested there is to issue two separate commands:

```
 rsync -av --ignore-existing --remove-source-files source/ destination/ && \
 rsync -av --delete `mktemp -d`/ source/
```

The last piece of the command suggested in these two posts,

```
 rmdir source/
```

which is needed to remove the (now emptied) source directory has this form in these posts because the OPs and the answers are using rsync to move large amounts of files within the same machine. In your case you will have to do this manually.

Comment: The `rsync --delete` suggestion is dangerous, because it ignores the possibility that the rsync wasn't completed, or there are new files at the source. @slhck's `find` method below is much safer.

Comment: This is an idiotic oversight over whoever wrote rsync, since directories are files too.

Comment: Although the `rsync --delete` command is only executed if the first `rsync` is successful because of the `&&` condition (compared to the argument of @Sai), I wouldn't use it, too, as it could be possible that something writes in the source directory, while the first rsync is doing it's job (race-condition). Instead, the `find` method is race-condition safe.

Answer (score 52):

The manpage mentions that it only removes non-dirs:

```
--remove-source-files   sender removes synchronized files (non-dirs)
```

This is expected behavior.

If you want to remove empty directories in your source, if there are still files left, do a:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

This will recurse, because it is using `find`, and only apply to´ empty directories (via the `-empty` option). `-delete` deletes those directories. (You cannot delete non-empty directories this way.)

If it's just one empty source directory, a `rmdir <directory>` will of course suffice.

Comment: yeah, this is the only solution.  it's kind of a silly missing feature of rsync... rsync knows when it's processed the last file in a directory... it's easy enough to remove the dir too if it's empty.

Comment: Beware that issuing "rm -rf" is race-condition prone and I discourage it.

Comment: Variant that doesn't erase the top level empty directory: `find some_dir -depth -type d -empty -not -path some_dir -delete`

Comment: @ErikAronesty It'd probably be be good to have an additional `--remove-dirs` flag, but not removing source dirs is the only safe option as a default. A tree of empty directories takes up negligible space and can just be ignored. Conversely, removing a directory tree could cause issues. If an app creates the directories `backup/{user1,user2}` when it starts but doesn't check for existence later, it would crash trying to write a new file into the non-existent `backup/user1/` dir!

Comment: Not sure how it was in older versions of find, but `-depth` and `-empty` aren't needed I think. I tested it and a) it starts with the deepest dir and b) it is not able to delete dirs which contain files.

Comment: @mgutt Interesting. It seems that for GNU find, "The ‘-delete’ action will fail to remove a directory unless it is empty.", and: "The use of the ‘-delete’ action on the command line automatically turns on the ‘-depth’ option." — perhaps it's different for older/other versions.

Comment: @cameron-tacklind or `find some_dir -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete`

Comment: @n0099 That's cleaner!

Answer (score 7):

Using "**rm -rf**" has an inherent race condition, you could namely delete files that were just created between the **rsync** and the **rm** invocations.

I prefer to use:

> rsync --remove-source-files -a server:incoming/ incoming/ &&
>
> ssh
>   server find incoming -type d -delete

This will NOT remove the directories if they are not empty.

Comment: The `rm -rf` will also remove files that were not transferred for some reason.

Comment: This answer misses the `-depth` option which instructs `find` to process in the right order. As a result of this miss, directories that contain only empty directories (possibly recursively) will not be deleted. The variant by @slhck has it right.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon "man find" in my system (Kubuntu 20.04) says: "The -delete action also implies -depth". So I think adding it explicitly is redundant.

Comment: @MauroMolinari what you write is technically true. Still it's closer to danger than the recommended answer, especially when you first test commands without delete, to be sure. Man find also says "When testing a find command line that you later intend to use with -delete, you should explicitly specify -depth in order to avoid later surprises.".

Answer (score 1):

Remove source files, then remove directories to be safe.

```bsh
# given this scenario where you generate folders 2014-01-01 etc.. that have an archive myfile.tar.gz
pushd $(mktemp -d)
mkdir 201{4..6}-{01..12}-{01..31}
for i in $(ls); do; touch $i/myfile.tar.gz;done;
```

```bsh
# find and rsync on 10 CPU threads directories that match ./2015-*
find /tmp/tmp.yjDyF1jN70/src -type d -name '2015-*' | \
parallel \
--jobs 10 \
--progress \
--eta \
--round-robin \
rsync \
--hard-links \
--archive --verbose --protect-args \
--remove-source-files \
{} /tmp/tmp.yjDyF1jN70/dest
```

```bsh
# now safely remove empty directories only
for i in $(ls /tmp/tmp.yjDyF1jN70/src); do; rmdir /tmp/tmp.yjDyF1jN70/src/$i; done;
```

> More on [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Answer (score -1):

`-m, --prune-empty-dirs` prune empty directory chains from file-list

`--force` force deletion of dirs even if not empty

Comment: That just prevents rsync from copying empty dirs. It doesn't delete empty dirs.