# rsync --remove-source-files that exist on remote

Tags: linux, rsync, data-transfer

I'm periodically calling `rsync --remove-source-files -r source/logs/ dest:logs/` to synchronize log files from a mobile unit with inadequate storage to my reliable server with ample storage.

Sometimes, because of unstable connections, the rsync fails. `--append` usually fixes any problems and moves on when a transfer was interrupted midway.

Sometimes however, the file is fully transferred but the indication of this is not transmitted back to the source. So the source, correctly, does not remove the source file.

The problem is that the next time the `rsync` is run, the file on the remote exactly matches the one locally. So rsync removes it from the list of files to transfer. This unfortunately means that the local file, that was correctly transferred, gets pruned from the transfer list and thus is not removed after a transfer.

Is there some option to rsync I'm missing or will I need to have a follow-up job that removes aging files?

Answer (score -1):

Please go through : [RSYNC Does Not Delete Source Directories](https://superuser.com/questions/676671/rsync-does-not-delete-source-directories/676688)

You can read examples of rsync command on page by using
    man rsync

I think it would be great if you have follow up job which will clear source files.
You can use "find" command to clear aging files.